# Ctlr+Enter doesn't work as Save Changes for Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams, stacks-editor

On public Stack Overflow pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while modifying the post closes the editor and saves the post content. But not on Stack Overflow for Teams, there is just a new line added like for regular <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Different editors. Teams uses a new, buggy, nigh-unusable version of the editor. Not surprising that it also swallows Ctrl+Enter.

Comment: Also reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360075/348196).